# How to force javascript to run after shortcode is executed on a WordPress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am writing a WordPress plugin to add text to a page using a shortcode. The text is created by javascript. See below the code I have so far.

```
function myplugin_register_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'myplugin_jquery', plugins_url('/js/myplugin-jquery.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );
    wp_register_style( 'myplugin_style', plugins_url('/css/myplugin-style.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
}
add_action('init', 'myplugin_register_script');

function myplugin_enqueue_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myplugin_jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myplugin_style' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_enqueue_script');

function myplugin_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    echo '<div class="mytext"></div>';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'myplugin-text', 'myplugin_shortcode' );
```

The javascript is supposed to add text to the mytext div. When I add the shortcode to a page the text is not added. There is a script error stating "Cannot read properties of null". I believe this happens because when the javascript is executed it can't find the mytext div on the page.

I tried moving the wp_enqueue_script inside the myplugin_shortcode() but I still get the same error.

```
function myplugin_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    echo '<div class="mytext"></div>';
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myplugin_jquery' );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'myplugin-text', 'myplugin_shortcode' );
```

I tested my script on a test.php file (outside WordPress) and it works when I load the javascript at the end of the page.

```
<body> 
    <?php 
        // Your PHP code here 
        echo "Hello, world!<br>";
        echo '<div class="mytext"></div>'; 
    ?> 
    <script src="myplugin-jquery.js"></script> 
</body>
```

I appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Since you did not use the last parameter of `wp_register_script` to let it add the script to the footer pf the page, it will be added to the head instead. And if your actual JS code then looks for the element directly, instead of waiting for DOMContentLoaded or load events to fire first, then it will of course not find the element.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. After I posted the question I kept searching for an answer and decided to check the parameters to the wp_register_script function. I found I could add a parameter to defer script execution until the DOM is loaded. That solved my issue. I am changed it to "wp_register_script( 'myplugin_jquery', plugins_url('/js/myplugin-jquery.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), false, array( 'strategy' => 'defer' ) );" I updated the question with this solution. Thank you.

Comment: _"I updated the question with this solution."_ - this is a Q&A site, so please don't put answers into the question. You can write a "self-answer", if you found the/a solution on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I posted the question I decided to read on the wp_register_script function and I realized I could add a parameter to "defer" the script execution until the DOM was loaded. See below how I fixed my problem:

```
wp_register_script( 'myplugin_jquery', plugins_url('/js/myplugin-jquery.js', FILE), array('jquery'), false, array( 'strategy' => 'defer' ) );
```

Thank you.